# Where to store/manage Session and global/stateless data using MVVM architecture in Android?

Tags: android, mvvm, singleton, android-livedata

Two cases :

```
1. Session data - For example the logged in User details, or some other session data.
2. Global/stateless data - A repository with retrofit client.
```

**for case 1** :
The easiest way is to use some sort of a Singleton, "DataManager/LoginManger" , but singletons are bad(testing, unpredictable states over time...)
Another way would be to use the Application class, which is also bad.

So where do we store that data?

**for case 2**:
A simple repository, which holds reference to Retrofit client for example or other clients.
Using this as a singleton makes more sense, as this class would be immutable/stateless. We would only ever want to create a retrofit client once.
But.. Testing?

**3**. Also, what if we want to fetch location ?
   We could have a LiveData responsible for that in the ViewModel. But ViewModel is scoped to a certain View/Activity. So that would mean that if we changed views (for example entered the settings from the drawer, while the homepage's viewmodel was fetching location) , we would lose the location data once it is retrieved, and then when the user comes back to the homepage, instead of just showing them the location, we would have to request the location all over again.

I haven't found any way that deals will all these cases. It seems there's no clear answer.

Comment: Any updates on this question?